# python- why does my program tells me it's not callable

Tags: python, xcode, python-2.7, debugging, helper

I made a class in python and when I tried to call it into another python file (after importing it) it doesn't recognizes it as a class but as an object and then it tells me that my class is not callable

here is my class:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self,value=9,isVissible=False):
        self.value=value
        self.isVisible=isVissible
    def setValue(self,value):
        self.value=value
    def setVisible(self):
        self.visible=True
```

and here is where I tried to call it:

```
import Cell,random
class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []
        for i in range(12):
            a = []
            for j in range(12):
                x = Cell()   <=== right here it's an error
.
.
.(the rest of my program)
```

and finally here is the error:

```
x=Cell()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

can anyone help me fix this, even my teacher didn't understand my mistake

Comment: you probably need to use `from cell import Cell`

Comment: I think you should import your class like `from <your_module_name> import Cell`

Comment: `Cell.Cell()` or `from Cell import Cell`

Comment: Please make an effort to reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program.

Comment: The issue is not reproductable.

Comment: You imported a *module*. modules are not callable.

Comment: Also note that Python is not Java and does not require this wtf "one-class-per-file" thing, so if you have two or more classes designed to work together just put them in the same module.

Answer (score 2):

The `Cell` has been used for both your imported module and your class. According to the error, python has mapped it to the module name. So, when you are writing `Cell()`, it tries to use the module name as a function, instead of calling the class constructor.

If the class `Cell` is inside the `Cell` module, use `Cell.Cell()` instead, or change your import to `from Cell import Cell`. Otherwise, rename either the module or the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement is wrong, you're importing a module called Cell instead of your Cell class. You should use lower case for your filenames and import it like so:

```
from cell import Cell


test = Cell()
```